SSLHandshakeException when connecting to OpenSearch (AWS) via Spark
I'm trying to write data into a OpenSearch managed service in AWS when running my code locally via IntelliJ. However everything I've tried and I can't seem to get past:
24/05/08 15:38:00 ERROR NetworkClient: Node [...] failed (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target); no other nodes left - aborting...

Which whlie the error is self explanatory, how do I solve it?
So far:
The code in spark I'm using to write looks like
object Spark {
  var uri = ""
  var username = ""
  var password = ""

  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "common/src/main/resources/rds-truststore.jks")
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit")

  val getOrCreate: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("opensearch.nodes", uri)
    .config("opensearch.port", "443")
    .config("opensearch.nodes.wan.only", "true")
    .config("opensearch.net.http.auth.user", username)
    .config("opensearch.net.http.auth.pass", password)
    .config("opensearch.net.ssl", "true")
    .config("opensearch.batch.size.bytes", "1kb")
    .config("opensearch.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed", "true")
    .getOrCreate()
}


I've tried a number of different combinations with the config options (setting ssl false, removing ssl config etc) but none seem to change anything.
I'm not sure the truststore is setup correctly, but I used the AWS article for how to create this, it should be the same?
The code which generates the trust store from the linked article:
mydir=./
truststore=${mydir}/rds-truststore.jks
storepassword=changeit

curl -sS "https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem" > ${mydir}/global-bundle.pem
split -p "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" ${mydir}/global-bundle.pem rds-ca-

for CERT in rds-ca-*; do
  alias=$(openssl x509 -noout -text -in $CERT | perl -ne 'next unless /Subject:/; s/.*(CN=|CN = )//; print')
  echo "Importing $alias"
  keytool -import -file ${CERT} -alias "${alias}" -storepass ${storepassword} -keystore ${truststore} -noprompt
  rm $CERT
done

rm ${mydir}/global-bundle.pem

echo "Trust store content is: "

keytool -list -v -keystore "$truststore" -storepass ${storepassword} | grep Alias | cut -d " " -f3- | while read alias
do
   expiry=`keytool -list -v -keystore "$truststore" -storepass ${storepassword} -alias "${alias}" | grep Valid | perl -ne 'if(/until: (.*?)\n/) { print "$1\n"; }'`
   echo " Certificate ${alias} expires in '$expiry'"
done


As far as I can tell in the AWS Console there is no ability to set custom certificates and whatnot with OpenSearch, so I'm not sure what else I should be looking at.
Edit:
I should note that I have no problems calling OpenSearch via Postman, or even the Java REST client in other applications without setting any SSL configuration. Its just Spark I can't seem to get a connection with.
I'm currently using  the "org.opensearch.client" % "opensearch-spark-20_2.12" % "1.0.1" package in my Spark app.
